# How to show the top row while I'm in row number 100?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a lot of data in Excel cells. However, the first row in my Excel file contains cells which represent titles of each cell beneath it. Now, if I'm in row number 100 and I'm filling information and every time I want to know which type of info the cell the cursor is highlighting at the moment I have to go the the top of the file to know that.

Is there a way that can let me know or see the first row while I'm far away beneath it?

Comment: Panel division. I'll post an answer with screenshots briefly.

Comment: freeze pane is how I'd do it

Comment: http://news.techgenie.com/files/How-to-Freeze-Panes-in-Microsoft-Excel-2007.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Freeze Panes](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-freeze-panes-in-an-excel-2010-worksheet.html).

### 1 -Position the cell cursor based on what you want to freeze:

Columns: Select the column to the right of the columns you want to freeze. For example, click any cell in column B to freeze column A.

Rows: Select the row below the rows you want to freeze. For example, click any cell in row 4 to freeze rows 1, 2, and 3.

Columns and rows: Click the cell below the rows and to the right of the columns you want to freeze — essentially, the first cell that isn't frozen. For example, click cell B2 to freeze both column A and row 1.

### 2- In the Window group of the View tab, choose Freeze Panes→Freeze Panes.

### 3- In the Window group of the View tab, choose Freeze Panes→Unfreeze Panes to unlock the fixed rows and columns.

You can click the Freeze Top Row or Freeze First Column command in the Freeze Panes drop-down menu to freeze just the top row or first column in the worksheet, without regard to the position of the cell cursor in the worksheet.

[image]

Comment: That's great. I love Microsoft and I love you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is called Freeze Panes.

I'm using Excel 2003 but I know this functionality exists on later versions. To access it on Excel 2003, do the following:

1. Assuming you had a data set like the following:

   [image: First point]
2. Select the cell **immediately** below the cells (header) you want to lock.
3. Go to Window > Freeze Panes.

   [image: Freeze Panes location on Excel 2003]
4. You now notice the black line dividing the data's header form the respective data.

   [image: End Result]

@Lorenzo stepped up with a good answer for Excel 2010 (and I'm not going to copy the work he made) so I'm keeping this here for information/curiosity purposes.